# Google App Engine trouble using Mail API

Tags: google-app-engine

Hello I have a contact form with a post method on my contacts page and want to be able to use the Mail API to send outgoing mail from my google app engine application So I decided to use the mail API and registered myself as an authorized sender on my developer console and initiated the command --enable_sendmail=yes applicationID however when I test it, it gives me this error. I'm still fairly new to google app engine and not sure why that is happening.

> ```
> "INFO 2015-08-06 18:44:50,935 mail_stub.py:142] MailService.Send
>      From: abdallahozaifa19527@gmail.com
>   To: Hozaifa
>   Subject: Test
> /bin/sh: 1: sendmail: not found
> ERROR    2015-08-06 18:44:50,944 mail_stub.py:263] Error sending mail using sendmail: [Errno 32] Broken pipe"
> ```

```
import os
import webapp2
import jinja2
from google.appengine.api import mail


template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir),
                           autoescape = True)

 class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self, *a, **kw):
            self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)

    def render_str(self, template, **params):
            t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
            return t.render(params)

    def render(self, template, **kw):
            self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))

 class MainPage(Handler):
    def get(self):
               self.render("index.html")

class AboutPage(Handler):
    def get(self):
               self.render("about.html")                   

class ProjectsPage(Handler):
    def get(self):
               self.render("projects.html")

class ExperiencePage(Handler):
    def get(self):
               self.render("experience.html")                  

class ContactPage(Handler):
    def get(self):
               self.render("contact.html")
    def post(self):
        name = self.request.get('name')
        email = self.request.get('email')
        message = self.request.get('message')

        if (name and email and message):
            message = mail.EmailMessage(sender="abdallahozaifa19527@gmail.com", subject="Test")
            message.to = "Hozaifa<abdallahozaifa19527@gmail.com>"
            message.send()
        else:
            self.write("It didnt work!")


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                            ('/about.html', AboutPage),
                            ('/projects.html', ProjectsPage),
                            ('/experience.html', ExperiencePage), 
                            ('/contact.html', ContactPage)])
```

Comment: Do you have sendmail installed? To send email from actual appengine, you can just deploy your app - it's only the SDK that doesn't send mail without an external program. Having it log to the terminal is normally enough for development.

Comment: I don't think so then, I thought that the development SDK had it but I couldn't find it, so you might be right Ill try to deploy it and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you sir!! it works when I deployed it!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code works, however it does not work with the google app engine SDK because the SDK doesn't have the send mail, I was trying to test it using the SDK, problem solved!

Comment: So accept your own answer, that's good etiquette on this site.

Comment: You can send mail using the sdk with this option: --smtp_host=smtp.of.your.provider

Comment: Yea it won't let me accept my own answer until 2 days.